# Why &a[N] doesn't invoke UB when N goes to out of bound?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, undefined-behavior

I saw in many examples it is written that:

```
 #define N 5
 ....

 int a[N], *p;
 ....

 for (p = &a[0]; p < &a[N]; p++);
```

It is clear that `a[N]` doesn't exist, then why compiler is not giving any warning (like out of bound) or error or does it invoke UB?

Comment: c compilers generally don't give bounds warnings. what compiler are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White; GCC-4.7.1

Comment: C compilers do not check bounds - they trust you to know something they don't :)

Comment: While `a[N]` might not exist, `&a[N]` sure does, as it's just `(a+N)`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: C compilers don't *necessarily* check bounds (and most of them don't). But since accessing outside the bounds of an array has undefined behavior, one valid behavior is tripping a check.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The memory at `&a[N]` is never accessed by your program, so it's fine.  The C standard allows comparison of pointers within or one past the end of an array object.

Edit regarding discussion below:

`&a[N]` does *not* cause undefined behaviour - it is exactly equivalent to `a + N`.  From the C standard, **6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**, paragraph 3:

> The unary **`&`** operator yields the address of its operand … if the operand is the result of a **`[]`** operator, neither the **`&`** operator nor the unary **`*`** that is implied by the **`[]`** is evaluated and the result is as if the **`&`** operator were removed and the **`[]`** operator were changed to a **`+`** operator.

Comment: Isn't it technically accessed though? `&a[N]` is short for `&(*(a+n))`, so `a+n` is dereferenced and then referenced again right away. So I'm pretty sure this does invoke UB.

Comment: I'd imagine `&(*(a+n))` is just optimized to `(a+n)` - as long as you're not actually dereferencing it, I don't see why it should be UB.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen That's an implementation detail. It should be UB because dereferencing a pointer that points outside the bounds of an array, which `a+N` does, invokes UB.

Comment: but `a+N` is just an address, it's not actually dereferencing anything. Similar to how `NULL` is just an address, but it won't cause an exception unless you try to dereference it.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen a+N is just an address. `*(a+N)` dereferences that address. You're saying `&a[N]` is the same as `a+N`, but that's not what the standard says. The standard says that `a[N]` is the same as `*(a+N)`. Since there is no special case for using `&` on the result of `[]`, that means that `&a[N]` is the same as `&(*(a+N))`, which obviously invokes UB. The fact that `&(*(a+N))` could be optimized to `a+N` is irrelevant because that's an implementation detail.

Comment: @sepp2k; Man you are now confusing me! I have just read that `a + i` is same as `&a[i]`.

Comment: But if you treat `&` and  `[]` separately, aka derefence then re-reference, how would it know what the address is in the first place? The compiler would have to know that `&(*(x))` is just `x`, and it *shouldn't* try to dereference `x`. Unless it decides to compute `*(x)` and discard it, since the value is irrelevant to computing the address of it.

Comment: @haccks `&a[i]` is the same as `&(*(a+i))`. If `i` is in bounds, that happens to be the same as `a+i`, but if it's not, I'm pretty sure it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen You're again talking about how the language is implemented. I'm talking about how it's defined.

Comment: @sepp2k so just to make sure I understand, you're saying that `a+i` should invoke UB if `i` is not in the bounds of `a`?

Comment: It's most certainly not UB.  I'll dig up a spec quotation momentarily.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen No, I was saying that `*(a+i)` should invoke UB if `i` is out of bounds - no matter what that expression is used as an operand to. I'm perfectly aware that `a+n` is legal if `a` is an array of size `n`. As it turns out I was wrong - I just checked and the standard does specifically say that `&foo[bar]` shall be the same as `foo+bar`. So my bad.

Comment: @CarlNorum okay that's what I thought, and @sepp2k I completely agree that `*(a+i)` is UB if `i` is out of bounds.

Comment: Here you go: "The unary **`&`** operator yields the address of its operand. ... if the operand is the result of a **`[]`** operator, neither the **`&`** operator nor the unary **`*`** that is implied by the **`[]`** is evaluated and the result is as if the **`&`** operator were removed and the **`[]`** operator were changed to a **`+`** operator."  From **6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**, paragraph 3.

Comment: @hackks and @DrewMcGowan - you are right - `&a[i]` is exactly `a + i`.

Comment: I'm going to edit that bit into the answer; I think it's relevant enough.  It certainly caused a lot of discussion here.